# Is there anyway to set a custom format structure for the json export from scrapy? If yes, then how?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am totally new to python and scrapy stuff and scrapy documentations are not exactlly noob friendly. I made a spider for my school project which scrapes the data I want successfully but the problem is with the formatting in json export.
This is just a mock of how my code looks like;

```
def parse_links(self, response):
    products  = response.css('qwerty')
    for product in products:
        yield {
            'Title' : response.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').get()
            'URL' : response.url,
            'Product' : response.css('product').getall(),
            'Manufacturer' : response.xpath('Manufacturer').getall(),
            'Description' : response.xpath('Description').getall(),
            'Rating' : response.css('rating').getall(),
            }.
```

The export in json looks something like this;

`[{"Title": "x", "URL": "https://y.com", "Product": ["a", "e"], "Manufacturer": ["b", "f"], "Description": ["c", "g"], "Rating": ["d", "h"]}]`.

[To be precise this is how it looks now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQJqm.png)

But I want the data to be exported in this format;

`[{"Products": [{"Title":"x","URL":"https://y.com", "Links":[{"Product":"a","Manufacturer":"b","Description":"c","Rating":"d"},{"Product":"e","Manufacturer":"f","Description":"g","Rating":"h"}]}]}]`

[This is how I want the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCCIE.png)

I tried somethings from web but nothing worked and I couldn't find any explanatory documents in Scrapy site. The ones provided are not easy to understand for someone new like me as I said earlier. So any help would be great for me. I made the scraper pretty easily but have been stuck on this for a day.
FYI I am not using any custom pipeline and items.

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one json parsing

```
def parse_links(self, response):
products  = response.css('qwerty')
for product in products:
    AllResopnse = []
    Links = []
    Links.append({"Product":response.css('product').getall(),"Manufacturer":response.xpath('Manufacturer').getall(),"Description":response.xpath('Description').getall(),"Rating":response.css('rating').getall()})
    TitleDict = {"Title":response.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').get(),"URL":"https://y.com","Links":Links}
    ResponseData = {"Products":[TitleDict]}
yield ResponseData
```